# Since my insecure rails app is for personal use only, would basic HTTP authentication make it safe enough to deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku

There are a couple insecurities in my app. One is the ability to type ruby commands into html forms. The commands are executed server side to produce the response. Another is to enter a URL into an html forms and display some unescaped content from that page.

Despite these insecurities, I'll be the only one using it, so I'm wondering if it's safe enough to just use basic http authentication by adding the following to application controller:

`http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ENV["NAME"], :password => ENV["PASSWORD"]`

I want to deploy to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Authentication credentials aren't encrypted, so you should use HTTPS.

There also isn't any standard way to "log out" so the browser may retain the authentication when you walk away.  You may want to have a log out page that has some javascript...

```
<script>
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this which is simple like `http_basic_authenticate_with`? `ActionController::HTTPAuthentication` has  `Digest` and `Token` modules in addition to `Basic`. I'm hoping Devise is unneccesary since there is no user system.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... it's already very simple and you've given your own example.  `http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "maxpleaner", :password => "mysecretpassword"`   ... that's all you need to do to turn on basic authentication.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a similarly easy way to use HTTPS.

Comment: in your config/application.rb include this... `config.force_ssl = true`

Answer (score 0):

If you have any concerns at all about security a better approach may be to use a self signed or free StartSSL certificate and to implement basic authentication with Devise or something similar. This is fairly easy to do and will give you well tested and secure authentication as a starting point.